# How to store data after refreshing the web page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

So I built an app which keeps track of my monthly budget - expenses, incomes, percentages etc. The problem that I am trying to solve here is that when I add my items into the user interface (the front end) is that I want them to stay there, with the total budget after I reload the page, because right now they have values in the HTML code which I changed to zeros. I have been told that there is something to do with JSON here, but I do not know how to work with it. If someone could help me out it would be really appreciated. I can not paste the whole code because it is 450 lines of javascript.

I have tried different methods but none of them worked.

```
// GLOBAL APP CONTROLER
var controller = (function(budgetCtrl, UICtrl) {

    var setupEventListeners = function() {
        var DOM = UICtrl.getDOMstrings();

        document.querySelector(DOM.inputBtn).addEventListener('click', ctrlAddItem);

        document.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
            if (event.keyCode === 13 || event.which === 13) {

                ctrlAddItem();

            }
        });

        document.querySelector(DOM.container).addEventListener('click', ctrDeleteItem);

        document.querySelector(DOM.inputType).addEventListener('change', UICtrl.changedType);
    };

    var updateBudget = function() {

        // 1. Calculate the budget
        budgetCtrl.calculateBudget();

        // 2. Return Budget
        var budget = budgetCtrl.getBudget(); // the getBudget method only returns the budget,inc,exp and %

        // 3. Display the budget on the UI
        UICtrl.displayBudget(budget);
    };

    var updatePercentages = function() {
        // 1. Calculate the percentages
        budgetCtrl.calculatePercentages();

        // 2. Read percentages from budget controller
        var percentages = budgetCtrl.getPercentages();

        // 3. Display the percentages on the UI
        UICtrl.displayPercentages(percentages);
    };

    var ctrlAddItem = function () {
        var input, newItem;

        // 1. Get the field input data
        input = UIController.getInput();

        // we check if there is an input description or value so the code runs
        if (input.description !== '' && !isNaN(input.value) && input.value > 0) {
            // 2. Add the item to the budget controler
            newItem = budgetCtrl.addItem(input.type, input.description, input.value);

            // 3. Add the new item to the UI
            UICtrl.addListItem(newItem, input.type);

            // 4. Clear the fields
            UICtrl.clearFields();

            // 5. Calculate and update Budget
            updateBudget();

            // 6. Calculate and update percentages
            updatePercentages();
        }
    };

    var ctrDeleteItem = function(event) {
        var itemID, splitID, type, ID;

        itemID = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id; // parentNode gets the parent of the target of the event

        if (itemID) {

            // inc-1
            splitID = itemID.split('-'); // split returns an array with the other items except the '-'
            type = splitID[0];
            ID = parseInt(splitID[1]);

            // 1. Delete the item from the data structure
            budgetCtrl.deleteItem(type, ID);

            // 2. Delete the item from the UI
            UICtrl.deleteListItem(itemID);

            // 3. Update and show the new budget
            updateBudget();

            // 4. Calculate and update percentages
            updatePercentages();
        }

    };

    return {
        init: function() {
            console.log('Application has started.');
            UICtrl.displayMonth();
            // 3. Display the budget on the UI
            UICtrl.displayBudget({
                budget: 0,
                totalInc: 0,
                totalExp: 0,
                percentage: -1
            });
            setupEventListeners();
        }
    }


})(budgetController, UIController);;
```

I am currently storing the data in the Data controller

```
// BUDGET CONTROLLER
var budgetController = (function() {

    // we create a constructor 
    var Expense = function(id, description, value) {
        this.id = id;
        this.description = description;
        this.value = value;
        this.percentage = -1;
    };

    // this method in the prototype of expense calculates %
    Expense.prototype.calcPercentage = function(totalIncome) {

        if (totalIncome > 0) {
            this.percentage = Math.round((this.value / totalIncome) * 100); 
        } else {
            this.percentage = -1
        }
    };

    // this method in the prototype of expense returns the %
    Expense.prototype.getPercentage = function() {
        return this.percentage;
    };

    var Income = function(id, description, value) {
        this.id = id;
        this.description = description;
        this.value = value;
    };

    var calculateTotal = function(type) {
        var sum = 0;
        data.allItems[type].forEach(function(cur) {
            sum += cur.value;
        });
        data.totals[type] = sum;
    };

    // we store the incomes' description in all items array and the price in the totals
    var data = {
        allItems: {
            exp: [],
            inc: []
        },
        totals: {
            exp: 0,
            inc: 0
        },
        budget: 0,
        percentage: -1
    };
```

Comment: currently, where are you storing values?

Comment: Have you tried Web session or localstorage ?

Comment: I am currently storing the values in a data controller

Answer (score 1):

Try `localstorage` for storing data

```
localStorage.setItem('test', 1);
alert( localStorage.getItem('test') );
```

Comment: Can you help me with something more specific - I have provided more code above.

Answer (score 1):

A few options for you:

1. You'll probably want to store the data in some form of server-side storage. How you do that is too broad a topic for an SO answer.
2. You *can* use browser-based storage ([`localStorage`](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/)), just be aware that if you "clear browsing data" this data would be amongst the things you're clearing.
3. You can also store the data in files that you upload into your page and then download from your page.

For both #2 and #3, you'd probably want to use [JSON](https://json.org) as your storage format. I'll start with #2 and then talk about how you would adjust it to #3:

On page load, you'd load and parse the data from `localStorage`:

```
var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("yourData")) ||  {
   thisFigure: 0,
   thatFigure: 0,
   theOtherFigure: 0
};
```

The `|| {/*...*/}` part provides a default for the first time when the data isn't there.

Each time you change something, you save your data to `localStorage`:

```
localStorage.setItem("yourData", JSON.stringify(data));
```

Now, if you want to store it in files you can upload to your page and download from your page, you'll need to use a `FileReader` for upload, reading the data via [`readAsText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsText) and then using `JSON.parse` on it as above. To create the file to download, you'd create a [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) containing your JSON string from `JSON.stringify` (the linked MDN page shows how to do that) and make it available as a link, which you'd then click and save to your local disk.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the browser's localstoratge. It is available in most modern browsers

```
localStorage.setItem('Key', "Value");
let k = localStorage.getItem('Key');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store data on client using [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

For example:

```
localStorage.setItem('language', 'js');
```

where 'language' is key and 'js' is value you want to store.

In your case you can convert your data to JSON, put it in localStorage and after page refresh check if localStorage is not empty on your key and convert it back from JSON to object