# Why isn't the value in my variable (totalSubs) permanently changed with the new assignment after the runSubs funtion?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

When the page is reloaded, totalSubs returns back to its original value of 10. Why is this?

```
var totalSubs = 10;
window.onload = function getSubs() {
document.getElementById('subsNo').textContent= totalSubs;

}

function runSubs() {
var subsNo = Number(document.getElementById('subsNo').textContent);
var NewSubsNo = 0;
NewSubsNo = subsNo + 1;
document.getElementById('subsNo').textContent= NewSubsNo;
return NewSubsNo; 
}

totalSubs = runSubs(totalSubs);

<input type="submit" value="Subscribe" style="width:200px; height:60px; font-size: 2.0rem;" onclick="runSubs()"  onload="getSubs()" />

<p id="subsNo"> </p>
```

Backend:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs'); 
http.createServer(function (req, res) {   
  fs.readFile('MobileUI.html', function(err, data) {     
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.write(data);
  return res.end();
  });
}).listen(8080);
```

Comment: _"When the page is reloaded, totalSubs returns back to its original value of 10. Why is this?"_ Because of `var totalSubs = 10;`

Comment: @jabaa But I changed the assignment further down the line. That should be the new legitimate assignment.

Comment: Everytime you load/reload the page, the line is evaluated and `totalSubs` is initialized with 10. Then `getSubs` is called.

Comment: @jabaa how do I make the new assignment the result of the runSubs function — for all other times after the first?

Comment: You can store the value in [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) and read it from there

Comment: @jabaa what does that mean? How would I do that?

Comment: @0xd6438c just making sure, are you aware that *state* is not persisted across page reloads in client javascript code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to store data after refreshing the web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58166154/how-to-store-data-after-refreshing-the-web-page)

Comment: @jabaa I don't think local storage would work since the code would be public-facing. Each different user who clicks the button changes the value of totalSubs. Each change made by each different user needs to be general to the public, not local to their own browser.

Comment: In that case you need a backend.

Comment: @jabaa an external js in the server? Just tried it now and the problem repeats. Moved the totalSubs variable declaration there and it works just like the files were contiguous. Still returns back to 10 when I refresh the page.

Comment: You need a server. Read the value using AJAX from the server and update it there.

Comment: @jabaa created a js file with this and ran it:

```var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  fs.readFile('MobileUI.html', function(err, data) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write(data);
    return res.end();
  });
}).listen(8080); ```

the html and script are in MobileUI.html. This way, every single time a user clicks  the subscribe button, the entire html is being reloaded from the server and there's no pre-loading to the browser, right?

Still doesn't work. Reloading the browser returns totalSubs back to 10

Comment: You have to store the value on the server, either in memory or in some kind of a database.

Comment: In my opinion, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX) is best, beginner-friendly source.

Answer (score -1):

Store it in the localStorage of a web browser. Currently, you are storing in temporary memory so instead, use local storage.

```
localStorage.setItem('totalSub', 10);
const getSub = local.getItem('totalSub')
```

Comment: Wouldn't work. Each different user who clicks the button changes the value of totalSubs. Each change made by each different user needs to be general to the public, not local to their own browser.

Comment: Ohh I see what you are talking about. Yeah, The only way we can do it is with the help of the database If it needs to be general. Or store the value in the file. The web browser and array store the data temporarily so it will get lost once you refresh the page. You need a way to retain the totalSubValue